# .Net Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, multithreading

In what condition the principal is lost for the current thread. 
I have an Windows Form application that uses principal for main thread and receive notification via WCF from a server. On some clients I loose the Principal for the current thread and I don't understand why.
The "lost" seems to be from the code:

```
foreach (EventHandler subscriber in onApplicationIdle.GetInvocationList())
{
    subscriber.BeginInvoke(this, e, OnAsyncCompleted, subscriber);
}
```

Comment: can you post some code, and at which point `CurrentPrincipal` "disappears"?

Comment: I am trying to understand why is lost. The code where I see is foreach (EventHandler subscriber in onApplicationIdle.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    subscriber.BeginInvoke(this, e, OnAsyncCompleted, subscriber);
                }

Comment: I mean add more info about your application flows. Something like "Calling WCF Service -> Receive async response-> UpdateUI (here `CurrentPrincipal` is null)". Just post some wider scope of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new thread in .NET the principal of the parent thread is not automatically propagated. You must do that yourself if you are making the thread.

If you are using `async` I believe it has its own rules for identity propagation in any threads it creates.

Calling `BeginInvoke` puts the method in the ThreadPool (I believe!) so thread pool principals apply here. I think that means you have to do it yourself!

You can have all threads YOU make set the principal automatically by invoking [AppDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setprincipalpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx), but this only covers the three types in the [PrincipalPolicy enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.principalpolicy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Otherwise its up to you in the threaded code to set the Thread.Current.Principal() by hand.

Please see the [wrong-thread-currentprincipal-in-async-wcf-end-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008509/wrong-thread-currentprincipal-in-async-wcf-end-method) Stack overflow post for a similar discussion.